# jQuery: Color fade

Tags: jquery, colors, fade

Is it possible to have 2 colors (red, green) and give the percentage of fading.

***Example:***

black (#000000) => white (#ffffff) --- Percent: 50% ***=>*** grey (#808080)

Is this maybe possible with [jQuery xcolor](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/), if yes, how?

(the xcolor.analogous example return circa the colors I want to have, but how could I set the percentage of fading?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have almost answered your own question: The xcolor plugin you point to has exactly the method you want:

```
$.xcolor.gradientlevel(color, color, position, size)
```

Your example would be:

```
$.xcolor.gradientlevel("#000000", "#ffffff", 50, 100)
```